# How to serialize ForeignKey in Django rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the latest version of django rest framework.

I have this model:

```
class Subscriptions(models.Model):

subs_list = models.ForeignKey(SubsList, verbose_name='Subscription list', on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='subs_list')  # идентификатор подписного листа
subscriber = models.ForeignKey(Subscribers, verbose_name='Subscriber', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # идентификатор подписчика
created_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Created date', auto_now=True)  # дата добавления подписчика в подписной лист
deleted = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Deleted')  # True-удален из подписного листа, False/null-в подписном листе
```

How do I serialize it? The main question is how to serialize ForeignKey, that would be associated with the query related data, i.e. NOT:

```
"id": 29,
  "created_date": "2018-03-01T14:28:41.237742Z",
  "deleted": false,
  "subs_list": 1,
  "subscriber": 1
```

but like this

```
"id": 29,
  "subs_list": {
    "id": 1,
    "uuid": "d183bab7-af26-48f8-9ef5-ea48e09a95a9",
    "name": "TEST",
    "description": "TEST",
    "created_date": "2018-03-01T13:15:18.808709Z",
    "deleted": null,
    "user": 6
  },
  "subscriber": {
    "id": 1,
    "bot_id": "1",
    "name_messenger": "11",
    "username": "1",
    "first_name": "1",
    "last_name": "1",
    "created_date": "9999-03-01T16:47:51.440000Z",
    "subscribed": true,
    "chat_bot": "1",
    "phone": "1",
    "user": 1
  },
  "created_date": "2018-03-01T14:28:41.237742Z",
  "deleted": false
```

I have such a serializer:

```
...
class SubscriptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
subs_list = SubsListSerializer(read_only=True)
subscriber = SubscribersSerializer(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Subscriptions
    fields = '__all__'
```

When get requests everything is ok, but how to update and add data is not clear, error:
IntegrityError at /subscriptions/subscriptions/
null value in column "subs_list_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (41, 2018-03-01 16:10:02.383625+00, f, null, null).

I struggle with this problem for a very long time, read all the related answers, but there is no clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `read_only=True` and change your `serializer.py`  as below

```
class SubscriptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subs_list = SubsListSerializer()
    subscriber = SubscribersSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Subscriptions
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sub_lst = SubsList.objects.create(**validated_data['subs_list'])
        subscriber = Subscribers.objects.create(**validated_data['subscriber'])
        return Subscriptions.objects.create(subs_list=sub_lst, subscriber=subscriber, deleted=validated_data['deleted'])
```

And your `creation payload` will be like this,

```
{
    "subs_list": {
         "uuid": "d183bab7-af26-48f8-9ef5-ea48e09a95a9",
         "name": "TEST",
         "description": "TEST",
         # etc etc
         },
    "subscriber": {
                "bot_id": "1",
                "name_messenger": "11",
                "username": "1",
                # etc etc
            },

            "deleted": null
        }
```

I think you have several `ForeignKey` relationships are there, so you have to map those things carefully in `create()`
Similar way, you can override `update()` and which can be used while API updation too.
See [this official doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) for more info

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this.


Error:
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": {
    "required": "This field is required.",
    "null": "This field may not be null.",
    "invalid": "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}."
  },
  "data": {
    "subs_list": [
      "This field is required."
    ],
    "subscriber": [
      "This field is required."
    ]
  }
}